# Why don't I get destructors called when using unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Here I am creating dynamically allocated array of S objects and I expect them to be destroyed by unique_ptr, which doesn't happen and I get this error

Command terminated by signal 11

and that means the program accessed memory which it shouldn't have accessed as far as I am concerned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class S{
    public:
        S(){std::cout<<"Constructor\n";}
        ~S(){std::cout<<"Destructor\n";}
};

int main() {
    S* arr=new S[4];
    {
        using namespace std;
        unique_ptr<S> ptr=unique_ptr<S>(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<S>` will assume it is managing a single object and effectively do `delete arr`.   Since `arr` was initialised using an the array form of operator `new`, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I would recommend that you don't allocate memory manually with `new` or `new[]` and instead use `make_unique`. In this case, you should just use `auto arr = make_unique<S[]>(4);`

Comment: @ErikNouroyan it is similar, but answer for Nikos is exception safe and KamilCuk is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> new s[4]
> ```

If you use `new[]` allocation you have to destroy it using `delete[]`, not `delete`.

```
    auto ptr = unique_ptr<S[]>(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I know what happens in my case if I ommit that? I mean what happens internally?

Comment: `in my case if I ommit that?` Undefined behavior. `I mean what happens internally?` No idea, you'll have to read the source code of your standard library implementation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is recommended

Comment: @ErikNouroyan Internally, the `unique_ptr` version is instantiated that calls `delete` in its destructor instead of `delete[]`.. Since you allocated memory using `new[]` instead of `new`, you get undefined behavior, which in this case happens to result in a signal 11 abort.

Comment: @NikosC. but I don't know why it works for int[] and not S[] , I have no idea why that is so

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sure, it is the constructor for unique_ptr

Comment: @ErikNouroyan You can't really argue why something does or does not happen when you have undefined behavior. In this case, it might have something to do that `int` is a basic type and has no destructor. But really, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @TedLyngmo template<class U> explicit unique_ptr( U p ) this one I guess U is replaced with S[]

Comment: @NikosC. alright, thanks

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's what is needed I guess, You take the ownership of the object and since it is of type S[] when coming out of scope the destructor for unique_ptr is called which does something similar to this delete[]

Comment: @ErikNouroyan Jeez ... I totally misread the whole thing (I saw `arr` as a size argument) ... sorry for the confusion. I'll delete my comments...

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's alright

Comment: This is a wrong usage. Normally, the result of  `new` must be used instantly by the final owner.